# getimagesize if width and height condition PHP

Tags: php, getimagesize

I need to validate an image pixel. I used getimagesize function and store it to a variable then using the 3rd index of the array I can look at its width and height. The question is, how could I make an if condition to allow only 80px width and 80px height of an image for an upload.

Answer (score 1):

Index 0 and 1 of the returned array from [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)() contain respectively the width and the height of the image.

```
$size = getimagesize( $filePath );
if( $size[0] > 80 || $size[1] > 80 ) {
    // too big
}
```

Comment: I should have read the PHP manual carefully.
Index 0 and 1 contains respectively the width and the height of the image. Index 3 contains the text string of both width and height. Thank you very much.